# Gradle task starts without invoking

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, javadoc, kotlin-dokka

I am trying to build javadoc using [Dokka](https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka) for javadoc and kotlindoc

```
task dokkaDoc(type: org.jetbrains.dokka.gradle.DokkaAndroidTask) {

    println("Inside the task dokkaDoc")

    moduleName = 'data'
    outputFormat = 'javadoc'
    outputDirectory = "$buildDir/docs/javadoc"

}



task taskA(type: Zip, dependsOn: dokkaDoc) {
    println("Starting task A")
    classifier 'dokkaDoc'
    extension "zip"
    from "$buildDir/docs/kotlindoc"
    archiveName 'a.zip'
}

task taskB(type: Zip, dependsOn: dokkaDoc) {

    println("Starting task B")
    classifier 'dokkaDoc'
    extension "zip"
    from "$buildDir/docs/kotlindoc"
    archiveName 'b.zip'

}
```

When I try to execute taskA, taskB also gets executed.

```
Output:
>gradlew :Project:a

> Configure project :Project
Inside the task dokkaDoc
Starting task A
Starting task B
```

Answer (score 1):

By adding `println` to the task definition, they are being printed at configuration time, not at runtime

You can change that to only print when the task is executed by adding a `doFirst` or `doLast` block to the task:

```
task dokkaDoc(type: org.jetbrains.dokka.gradle.DokkaAndroidTask) {
    doFirst {
        println "Running the task dokkaDoc"
    }
    moduleName = 'data'
    outputFormat = 'javadoc'
    outputDirectory = "$buildDir/docs/javadoc"
}

task taskA(type: Zip, dependsOn: dokkaDoc) {
    doFirst {
        println "Starting task A"
    }
    classifier 'dokkaDoc'
    extension "zip"
    from "$buildDir/docs/kotlindoc"
    archiveName 'a.zip'
}

task taskB(type: Zip, dependsOn: dokkaDoc) {
    doFirst {
        println "Starting task B"
    }
    classifier 'dokkaDoc'
    extension "zip"
    from "$buildDir/docs/kotlindoc"
    archiveName 'b.zip'
}
```

Comment: Why only the print statement in doFirst?

Comment: The build script gets effectively executed when it is parsed. This configures the tasks. If you move everything into a doFirst, your tasks won't be configured when it comes to execute them

Comment: When I run the taskA, DokkaAndroidTask is executed, builds the output directory as /docs/javadoc. But after that when I run taskB it does not build the output directory.

Comment: Not sure what you mean 